# user input and loop bug in python script

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

This is my first python project so thank you for your patience.

I have created a script to plot a route on pyplot depending on what route the user selects. To my amazement it actually works ,however, i am noticing a bug that I cannot iron out.

Once pyplot has generated a graph, it will only ask for the next input if i click on the red X to close the plot window. I want my code to produce the plot and continue to ask the user to input a new route number to plot. It is as if my code executes and then the loop stops and continues once i close the pyplot window.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

route001 = (3, 12, 'S', 'S', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'S', 'W',
            'W', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'W', 'N', 'N',
            'E', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'S', 'S', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S',
            'S', 'E', 'N', 'E', 'E')

route002 = (12, 11, 'W', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'W', 'W', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'W', 'W',
        'W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'N', 'N',
        'W', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'S')

route003 = (3, 12, 'S', 'S', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'W',
        'W', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'W', 'N', 'N', 'E',
        'E', 'S', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'S', 'S', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'E',
        'N', 'E', 'E')


while True:

route_selection = input('Select route 1, 2 or 3 ')
if route_selection == "1":
    selectedRoute = route001
elif route_selection == "2":
    selectedRoute = route002
elif route_selection == "3":
    selectedRoute = route003
else:
    print("error")

start = [selectedRoute[0]] + [selectedRoute[1]]
directions = selectedRoute[2:]
coordinates = {"N": [0, 1], 'E': [1, 0], 'S': [0, -1], 'W': [-1, 0]}
vector_list = []

def vectors():

    for d in directions:
        dx, dy = coordinates[d]
        start[0] += dx
        start[1] += dy
        if start[0] < 0 or start[0] > 12:
            print('Error: This route goes outside the grid')
            break
        elif start[1] < 0 or start[1] > 12:
            print('Error: This route goes outside the grid')
            break
        else:
            print(start)
            vector_list.append(start.copy())

vectors()
start_route = vector_list[0]
end_route = vector_list[-1]

def drone_plot():

    x = [p[0] for p in vector_list]
    y = [p[1] for p in vector_list]
    _, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xticks(range(13))
    ax.set_yticks(range(13))
    ax.plot(x, y, 'o-', color='blue')
    plt.grid()
    plt.axis([0, 12, 0, 12])
    plt.text(start_route[0], start_route[1], " START")
    plt.text(end_route[0], end_route[1], ' END')
    plt.title('Drone Route')
    plt.show()
drone_plot()
```

Comment: Does this help? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib/

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is very important in Python. You have a `while` loop with nothing in the loop, so the unindented code asking for input should only execute once. You code should look like this:

```
while True:

    route_selection = input('Select route 1, 2 or 3 ')
    if route_selection == "1":
        selectedRoute = route001
    elif route_selection == "2":
        selectedRoute = route002
    elif route_selection == "3":
        selectedRoute = route003
    else:
        print("error")
```

However, you should be careful, as the loop as it is seems to be an infinite loop. A loop that has `while True` should have some exit condition and `break` statement within it.